# Magento TTFB really slow 1+ minute after installing new theme

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, optimization

I installed a new theme on magento 1.7, and I also had to uninstall GTSpeed, seeing that was breaking the theme. And now I'm getting 1.9 minutes average [TTFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte) time. I don't believe it is because I uninstalled GTSpeed, there is too much difference.

I installed APC and Varnish, but it didn't help. Magento with the old theme (currently live) delivers the first byte in less than 0.6 seconds usually.

Here is the URL to the test slow version:
http://178.62.76.226/musicminds.ie/httpdocs/index.php/

What could possibly be causing this?

EDIT:
It's possibly something to do with the 2columns-left.phtml, when I changed the home page to 1 column the TTFB time went down to 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many possibilities as to what could cause the slowness since installing a new theme. Typically, it'll be because of badly written code though.

The best thing I can recommend, is to enable the profiler `System > Configuration > Developer > Debug > Profiler` as well as the `Developer Client Restrictions` setting under the Debug panel too. This will show where the bottleneck lies. And from there you can dig deeper and discover why it's so slow.

Furthermore, you should double check your Varnish configuration, by the sounds of it, it isn't working correctly. It should be caching the response from the web server, and giving you much faster speeds.

Comment: I've enabled the profiler, should I post the output here? is quite big.

Comment: If you could post it on gist.github.com and post the link that would be helpful. If you can filter out anything from it, please do :)

Comment: I disabled Varnish for now, because it was giving 503 error on the homepage, and it was working on other pages, it helped getting the time down in almost 10 seconds, even knowing that it helps, the server should never take 2 minutes to respond in a normal magento store, so there must be an error somewhere.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hmvar/59864b89c77c3f8f8285/  - here is the profiler

Comment: @HermanoVarussa I can see a few slow template files, take a look at the following files: `app/code/design/frontend/sm_g2shop/default/template/sm/supercategories/default_2.phtml` (66 seconds), `app/code/design/frontend/sm_g2shop/default/template/sm/basicproducts/recomend-home.phtml` (42 seconds). I suspect these are loading collections, or doing heavy database queries causing the slowness.

Comment: Yes, it was those blocks that were causing the slow down, they were loading a big category and all subcategories. I got them to work with only a small subcategory and it's much faster now. Thanks a lot for your help.